# Explicit 16⨯16 matrix representations of two-qudit entanglement witnesses

Tags: entanglement, quantum-state, entanglement-witness

I have a set of $16 \times 16$ two-qudit density matrices. I would like to study the bound-entanglement for this set, making use of entanglement witnesses for which explicit matrix representations are available or can be generated.

So to be fully explicit, can such a matrix (or matrices) be provided?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you asking for such a witness?

Answer (score 3):

Dariusz Chruscinski has provided me with an example of a particular such entanglement witness. It takes the form
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

Additionally, he has informed me that a second entanglement witness can be obtained by the replacement of the sixteen diagonal entries of the above matrix by 
\begin{equation}
{2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Some additional explanation (i.e. the thought process using which this matrix was arrived at) would be nice.

Comment: I will try to supply some further details.